Loading AWS DMS to Azure Databricks
I want to ingest and create a set of tables into a schema in Databricks. I already created the entire schema of several hundred tables in Databricks and now I just need to import the initial data load and periodically rerun for incremental loads.
Based on this tutorial, it should be a simple set of commands to import the DMS files from an S3 bucket into a Databricks schema but that tutorial is setting up a lot of extra stuff I don't need. My DMS S3 bucket is already present with csv files and now I just need to import them.
Here is the original script from that tutorial:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    input_file_name, regexp_extract, lit, current_timestamp, 
    when, to_timestamp, col, row_number
)
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StructType, StructField, StringType, TimestampType,
    IntegerType, BooleanType, DoubleType
)
import boto3
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from datetime import datetime

# AWS credentials
aws_access_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="aws-credentials-ANONYMOUS", key="aws-access-key")
aws_secret_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="aws-credentials-ANONYMOUS", key="aws-secret-key")

# Set Spark configurations
spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", aws_access_key)
spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", aws_secret_key)
spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com")

# Get all tables
s3_client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key,
    region_name='us-west-1'
)

def get_s3_files(bucket, prefix):
    """Get all files in S3 bucket with given prefix."""
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    files = []
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix):
        if 'Contents' in page:
            files.extend(page['Contents'])
    return sorted(files, key=lambda x: x['Key'])

def convert_schema_to_struct(schema_rows):
    """Convert schema rows from DESCRIBE TABLE to StructType."""
    fields = []
    for row in schema_rows:
        if row.col_name != 'creation_dt':  # Skip creation_dt as we handle it separately
            fields.append(StructField(row.col_name, StringType(), True))
    
    return StructType(fields)

def get_table_schema(table_name):
    """Get schema for a table from Databricks catalog."""
    schema_rows = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE bronze.myschema.{table_name}").collect()
    return convert_schema_to_struct(schema_rows)

def add_creation_dt_column(table_name):
    """Add creation_dt column if it doesn't exist."""
    columns = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE bronze.myschema.{table_name}").collect()
    if not any(row.col_name == 'creation_dt' for row in columns):
        spark.sql(f"""
            ALTER TABLE bronze.myschema.{table_name}
            ADD COLUMN creation_dt TIMESTAMP
        """)

def get_last_processed_timestamp(table_name):
    """Get the most recent creation_dt for a table."""
    result = spark.sql(f"SELECT MAX(creation_dt) as max_dt FROM bronze.myschema.{table_name}").collect()
    max_dt = result[0]['max_dt']
    return max_dt if max_dt else None

def process_file(table_name, file_path, is_initial_load, schema):
    """Process a single DMS file."""
    print(f"Processing file: {file_path}")
    print(f"Schema: {schema}")
    
    try:
        if is_initial_load:
            # Read CSV with proper quote handling
            df = spark.read.format("csv") \
                .option("header", "false") \
                .option("quote", "\"") \
                .option("escape", "\"") \
                .option("multiLine", "true") \
                .load(file_path)
            
            # Map _c0, _c1, etc. to schema columns
            column_mappings = [
                col(f"_c{i}").alias(field.name) 
                for i, field in enumerate(schema.fields)
            ]
            
            mapped_df = df.select(column_mappings)
            mapped_df.createOrReplaceTempView("source_data")
            
            # Insert the data with current timestamp
            spark.sql(f"""
                INSERT INTO bronze.myschema.{table_name}
                SELECT *, current_timestamp() as creation_dt
                FROM source_data
            """)
        else:
            # For incremental loads, read all columns
            raw_df = spark.read.format("csv") \
                .option("header", "false") \
                .option("quote", "\"") \
                .option("escape", "\"") \
                .option("multiLine", "true") \
                .load(file_path)
            
            # First column is operation, rest map to schema
            # Map _c1, _c2, etc. to schema columns (offset by 1 due to operation column)
            column_mappings = [
                col(f"_c{i+1}").alias(field.name) 
                for i, field in enumerate(schema.fields)
            ]
            
            # Handle deletes
            delete_df = raw_df.filter(col("_c0") == "D").select(
                col(f"_c1").alias(schema.fields[0].name)  # Primary key is first schema column
            )
            
            if delete_df.count() > 0:
                delete_df.createOrReplaceTempView("delete_records")
                spark.sql(f"""
                    DELETE FROM bronze.myschema.{table_name}
                    WHERE {schema.fields[0].name} IN (SELECT {schema.fields[0].name} FROM delete_records)
                """)
            
            # Handle inserts and updates
            upsert_df = raw_df.filter(col("_c0").isin(["I", "U"])) \
                .select(column_mappings)
            
            if upsert_df.count() > 0:
                # Deduplicate records by taking the last one for each primary key
                window_spec = Window.partitionBy(schema.fields[0].name).orderBy(lit(1))
                deduped_records = upsert_df \
                    .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(window_spec)) \
                    .filter(col("rn") == 1) \
                    .drop("rn")
                
                deduped_records.createOrReplaceTempView("upsert_records")
                
                # Generate column list for UPDATE SET clause
                update_columns = [f for f in schema.fields if f.name != schema.fields[0].name]
                update_sets = ", ".join([f"target.{f.name} = source.{f.name}" for f in update_columns])
                
                # Perform merge for all records
                spark.sql(f"""
                    MERGE INTO bronze.myschema.{table_name} target
                    USING (SELECT *, current_timestamp() as creation_dt FROM upsert_records) source
                    ON target.{schema.fields[0].name} = source.{schema.fields[0].name}
                    WHEN MATCHED THEN
                        UPDATE SET {update_sets}, target.creation_dt = source.creation_dt
                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                        INSERT *
                """)
        
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing file {file_path}: {str(e)}")
        raise
        return False

def format_timestamp(timestamp_str):
    """Convert filename timestamp to proper datetime format."""
    try:
        dt = datetime.strptime(timestamp_str, '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%f')
        return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    except ValueError:
        return None

def main():
    # Get all tables in bronze.myschema schema
    tables = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES IN bronze.myschema").select("tableName").collect()
    
    bucket = "wp-staging-data-lake-west"
    base_prefix = "inbound/production_db/my_app/"
    
    for table in tables:
        table_name = table.tableName
        print(f"Processing table: {table_name}")
        
        try:
            # Ensure creation_dt column exists
            add_creation_dt_column(table_name)
            
            # Get table schema
            schema = get_table_schema(table_name)
            
            # Get last processed timestamp
            last_timestamp = get_last_processed_timestamp(table_name)
            
            # Get all files for this table
            table_prefix = f"{base_prefix}{table_name}/"
            s3_files = get_s3_files(bucket, table_prefix)
            
            # Process initial load file if table is empty
            initial_load_file = next((f for f in s3_files if 'LOAD00000001.csv' in f['Key']), None)
            if last_timestamp is None and initial_load_file:
                file_path = f"s3a://{bucket}/{initial_load_file['Key']}"
                process_file(table_name, file_path, True, schema)
            
            # Process incremental files
            incremental_files = [f for f in s3_files if f['Key'].endswith('.csv') and 'LOAD00000001' not in f['Key']]
            for file in incremental_files:
                filename = file['Key'].split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
                if 'LOAD' not in filename:
                    formatted_timestamp = format_timestamp(filename)
                    if formatted_timestamp:
                        file_timestamp = datetime.strptime(formatted_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                        
                        if last_timestamp is None or file_timestamp > last_timestamp:
                            file_path = f"s3a://{bucket}/{file['Key']}"
                            process_file(table_name, file_path, False, schema)
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing table {table_name}: {str(e)}")
            continue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Here is my modified script trying to use the existing database schema already present in databricks to provide the schema information:
# Databricks notebook source
import dlt
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('dms_pipeline')

# S3 path configuration
data = "s3://wp-staging-data-lake-west/inbound/production_db/my_app"
logger.info(f"Initializing DMS pipeline with data path: {data}")

def get_table_schema(table_name):
    """Get schema from existing bronze.mydb table"""
    logger.info(f"Getting schema for table: {table_name}")
    schema_df = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE TABLE bronze.mydb.{table_name}")
    return schema_df.collect()

def get_tables_from_catalog():
    """Get list of tables from bronze.mydb catalog"""
    logger.info("Getting tables from bronze.mydb catalog")
    tables_df = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES IN bronze.mydb")
    tables = {}
    
    for table_row in tables_df.collect():
        table_name = table_row.tableName
        # Get schema to determine primary key (first column)
        schema = get_table_schema(table_name)
        primary_key = schema[0].col_name
        tables[table_name] = {'id': primary_key}
        logger.info(f"Found table: {table_name} with primary key: {primary_key}")
    
    return tables

def generate_tables(table, info):
    logger.info(f"Generating CDC and target tables for: {table}")
    
    @dlt.table(
        name=f"{table}_cdc_raw",
        table_properties={
            "quality": "bronze",
            "delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite": "true",
            "delta.autoOptimize.autoCompact": "true"
        },
        comment=f"Raw DMS data for table: {table}",
        temporary=True
    )
    def create_cdc_table():
        logger.info(f"Creating CDC raw table for: {table}")
        
        # Get schema from existing table
        schema = get_table_schema(table)
        column_names = [row.col_name for row in schema]
        
        # Read stream from S3
        stream = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
            .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
            .load(f"{data}/{table}")
        
        # For initial load (LOAD00000001.csv)
        initial_condition = input_file_name().contains("LOAD00000001.csv")
        
        # Add operation column and timestamp
        stream = stream \
            .withColumn("Op", 
                when(initial_condition, lit("I"))
                .otherwise(col("_c0"))) \
            .withColumn("dmsTimestamp",
                when(initial_condition, current_timestamp())
                .otherwise(
                    to_timestamp(
                        regexp_extract(input_file_name(), r"(\d{8}-\d{9})", 1),
                        "yyyyMMdd-HHmmssSSS"
                    )
                ))
        
        # Drop the operation column for initial load records and map columns
        base_cols = []
        for i, col_name in enumerate(column_names):
            if initial_condition:
                base_cols.append(col(f"_c{i}").alias(col_name))
            else:
                # For CDC files, skip the Op column by offsetting index
                base_cols.append(col(f"_c{i+1}").alias(col_name))
        
        stream = stream.select("Op", "dmsTimestamp", *base_cols)
        logger.info(f"Mapped columns for {table}: {column_names}")
        
        return stream.withColumn("_ingest_file_name", input_file_name())
    
    @dlt.table(
        name=f"{table}",
        table_properties={
            "quality": "silver",
            "delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite": "true",
            "delta.autoOptimize.autoCompact": "true"
        },
        comment=f"Merged DMS data for table: {table}"
    )
    @dlt.expect_all_or_drop({"valid_operation": "Op IN ('I', 'U', 'D') OR Op IS NULL"})
    def create_merged_table():
        logger.info(f"Creating/updating merged table for: {table}")
        
        return dlt.apply_changes(
            target=f"{table}",
            source=f"{table}_cdc_raw",
            keys=[info['id']],
            sequence_by=col("dmsTimestamp"),
            apply_as_deletes=expr("Op = 'D'"),
            except_column_list=["Op", "dmsTimestamp", "_ingest_file_name"],
            stored_as_scd_type=1
        )

# Main execution
logger.info("Starting DMS pipeline execution")

# Get tables from bronze.mydb catalog
tables = get_tables_from_catalog()
logger.info(f"Processing tables: {', '.join(tables.keys())}")

# Generate tables
for table, info in tables.items():
    try:
        logger.info(f"Starting processing for table: {table}")
        generate_tables(table, info)
        logger.info(f"Successfully processed table: {table}")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error processing table {table}: {str(e)}")
        raise

logger.info("DMS pipeline setup completed successfully")

Produces this error:
ERROR:SQLQueryContextLogger:[TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `bronze`.`mydb`.`delete_records` cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.
If you did not qualify the name with a schema, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct schema and catalog.
To tolerate the error on drop use DROP VIEW IF EXISTS or DROP TABLE IF EXISTS. SQLSTATE: 42P01
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 263, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.databricks.pipelines.SQLPipelineHelper.sqlWithAnalysisApi.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ExtendedAnalysisException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `bronze`.`mydb`.`delete_records` cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.
If you did not qualify the name with a schema, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct schema and catalog.
To tolerate the error on drop use DROP VIEW IF EXISTS or DROP TABLE IF EXISTS. SQLSTATE: 42P01; line 1 pos 15;
'DescribeRelation false, [col_name#184549, data_type#184550, comment#184551]
+- 'UnresolvedTableOrView [bronze, mydb, delete_records], DESCRIBE TABLE, true

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.tableNotFound(package.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$2(CheckAnalysis.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$2$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis0(CheckAnalysis.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis0$(CheckAnalysis.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis0(Analyzer.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1(CheckAnalysis.scala:198)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis$(CheckAnalysis.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$2(Analyzer.scala:443)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:443)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:443)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:264)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$5(QueryExecution.scala:562)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionPhase(SQLExecution.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$4(QueryExecution.scala:562)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:561)
    at com.databricks.util.LexicalThreadLocal$Handle.runWith(LexicalThreadLocal.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$1(Dataset.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$withActiveAndFrameProfiler$1(SparkSession.scala:1280)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActiveAndFrameProfiler(SparkSession.scala:1280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:104)
    at com.databricks.pipelines.SQLPipeline$.analyze(SQLPipeline.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.pipelines.SQLPipeline$.sqlWithAnalysisApi(SQLPipeline.scala:494)
    at com.databricks.pipelines.SQLPipelineHelper$.sqlWithAnalysisApi(SQLPipeline.scala:442)
    at com.databricks.pipelines.SQLPipelineHelper.sqlWithAnalysisApi(SQLPipeline.scala)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1554.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:397)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:199)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

I'm relatively new to databricks but feels like this should be simpler to achieve.

modify the process_file function in your script to handle the case where the delete_records table does not exist.

What is the location of the dlt pipeline? if you choose destination as unity catalog what is the catalog and schema name or if you choose hive metastore what is the location and target schema?

The code is currently just running in a notebook but I will eventually connect it to run as a pipeline job recurring. I'm just letting it run as the default for the catalog storage which I believe is unity catalog. Rather than trusting some flat file blob container storage I was opting to pull from the table schema I already loaded in databricks for schema information.

make sure bronze.mydb.delete_records is available in your default catalog.


ERROR:SQLQueryContextLogger:[TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view bronze.mydb.delete_records cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog. If you did not qualify the name with a schema, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct schema and catalog. To tolerate the error on drop use DROP VIEW IF EXISTS or DROP TABLE IF EXISTS.

The error message indicates that the table bronze.mydb.delete_records cannot be found.
This ERROR says that the table might not exist in the specified catalog and schema
You can use the DESCRIBE TABLE command and to use the IF EXISTS clause to avoid errors if the table does not exist.
SHOW TABLES IN bronze.mydb;
def get_table_schema(table_name):
       """Get schema from existing bronze.mydb table"""
       logger.info(f"Getting schema for table: {table_name}")
       schema_df = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE TABLE IF EXISTS bronze.mydb.{table_name}")
       return schema_df.collect()

Also make sure that your DLT pipeline is correctly configured and that the tables are being created as expected.
@dlt.table(
       name="bronze_table",
       table_properties={"quality": "bronze"}
   )
   def create_bronze_table():
       return (
           spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
           .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
           .load("s3://path-to-your-data")
       )

